# Send Emails From SharePoint Online Application From Specific Email Address

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, sharepoint-email, power-automate

We have a number of applications built on SharePoint Online.  Those applications are using Microsoft Flow (Power Automate) in some cases to alert people of events in the application.  These email alerts are sent from SharePoint Online to our internal users in our organisation.  By default, emails come from the email address "no-reply@sharepointonline.com".  These emails often get flagged as spam by our perimeter software for emails.

Our requirement is to change the from address to be a specific email address for each application e.g. "app-1@mycompany.com".

Is there a way to change the address that emails come from in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way to change the from adress:

1.choose send an emial (Office 365 Outlook) action:

[image]

2.Then click show advanced options, specify the user in from adress:

[image]

[image]

Comment: in this example does the email account need to be in O365 Exchange?

Comment: Yes, you are right.